# Tag name of response type automatically added by ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, api

I created a Web API that response the output type is byte[] which is an XML serialization object.
I test using Postman, the response seems OK look like this :

```
"PENhcmRHXR.....ZXdheT4="
```

But when the client testing my API using their code, the response is:

```
<base64Binary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">PENhcmRHXR.....ZXdheT4=<base64Binary>
```

So, do you know what is the reason of this strange case ? And if that error because of my code, so what should I do ?

Comment: With the less information about, what your client ist doing, I think he is just not using Postman ;-)

Comment: Yes, he makes his test code by himself.

Comment: Maybe the request header sent by your client contains, that the response should be XML?!

Comment: yes, the response expected in XML. and I return the byte[] of that XML serialization object

Comment: Sorry, then I seem not to understand, what the problem is. The request sent via _Postman_ doesn't contain the header. So I think, that's the reason, why you receive _plain/text_ there. Your client requests _XML_ and receives _XML_.

Comment: do you know hơ to config in Postman tochange the header ?, I only put the request Body xml, type raw xml/text and send the request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187636/discussion-between-hiennd-and-schlonzo).

Comment: When I added Accept header information, the response has that tag surround the response.

Comment: That's what you wanted, right?